# Spark running Liblinear unable to load JBLAS jar

Tags: scala, maven, jar, apache-spark, liblinear

I'm running spark 1.4.0, hadoop 2.7.0, and JDK 7. I'm trying to run the example code of Liblinear presented [here.](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/distributed-liblinear/spark/running_spark_liblinear.html)

The liblinear jar works, however when training the model it can't find the JBLAS library. I've tried including a JBLAS library in the --jars option when launching spark, as well as installing the jar with maven (although I must add I am a newbie to spark as well as maven so I probably did it wrong).

The specific error thrown is this:

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jblas/DoubleMatrix
    at tw.edu.ntu.csie.liblinear.Tron.tron(Tron.scala:323)
    at tw.edu.ntu.csie.liblinear.SparkLiblinear$.tw$edu$ntu$csie$liblinear$SparkLiblinear$$train_one(SparkLiblinear.scala:32)`
```

when running this line:

```
    val model = SparkLiblinear.train(data, "-s 0 -c 1.0 -e 1e-2")`
```

Thanks.

Comment: SparkLiblinear isn't a Spark package! You should ask the provider of the library who might have added a level of abstraction to simplify the use of Spark. This is not a question that can be answered on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jblas/DoubleMatrix

It seems that you did not add jblas jar. The solution could be:

```
$ export SPARK_CLASSPATH=$SPARK_CLASSPATH:/path/to/jblas-1.2.3.jar
```

After that, it would work fine.

Hope this helps,

Le Quoc Do